# Should I use web-socket when my internet connectivity is unstable (for messaging app)?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have 2 clients who sent messages to each other on mobile devices (using website).

Currently each client does an ajax call every 1 second to the server to check for new messages , so even when there is no internet connectivity , when it comes back the messages reappearing.

I would like to try web sockets (for real time connectivity and and learn new technology on the way) but I'm not sure what to do once the internet connectivity goes down and comes back (that the web socket is not connected anymore ...)

I'm looking for something that will always stay connected and when connectivity goes down and comes back , than it auto reconnect.

Answer (score 1):

If you use socket.io on your website (browser) and sockets on server (for example, express.io) then you have an option on socket.io to reconnect automatically when device has internet again:
http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#io#protocol

(at previous link, see "reconnection" options inside section io protocol)

Comment: I have clients running on localhost and main app on remote server , is the socket.io enough to let the localhost clients talk with the remote hosted site ? Noticed I need to install node.js now also on my website

Comment: Yes, socket io is enough. On server side yes, you need a server like nodejs to support websockets. You have alternatives on django and php but are a pain in the ass, to this functionality the easy solution is node.

Comment: on server side I need to run node on command line and make sure its always running ?

Comment: yes, you could use https://github.com/foreverjs/forever With forever, if node down then forever will up again.

Comment: Just tried socket.io chat example , ran the js on port 8787 , opened firewall on the remote server , on my local pc Ive set : var socket = io.connect('http://remoteserver:8787'); and the chat example not working , getting error : net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Just remember to incorporate your own detection of dead connection. Basically you have to implement your on ping/pong mechanism, a piece of data (like a json message `{ping:true}`) that you send from server every X time to client. If client does not reply in a given time, the server considers the client connection dead and disconnect. If client does not get a ping from server in a while, client considers the connection dead and reconnects.

Comment: So this means I need to have timers on my clients which is similiar to have ajax call every interval... no ?

Comment: More or less. There is no reliable way of knowing from the browser if the connection is dead or not. The WebSocket standard defines a ping/pong mechanism, but unfortunately the javascript API has no way of using it, or finding out. You can do it without timers as well, for example every time you get a ping from the server store the timestamp, and if at the time of sending anything the time stamp is too old, just recconnect before sending. WebSocktets are more used to allow the server to push data to clients, if you are just sending from the clients, there is little benefit.